# Как привязать proxy к этому коду

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

обьясните, пожалуйста, как привязать к этому коду прокси.

```
import lxml.html
import requests
 
login = 'log'
password = 'pass'
url = 'https://vk.com/'
 
headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language':'ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'DNT':'1'
}
session = requests.session()
data = session.get(url, headers=headers).content
page = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
 
form = page.forms[0]
form.fields['email'] = login
form.fields['pass'] = password
 
response = session.post(form.action, data=form.form_values())
if 'onLoginDone' in response.text:
    print('Валидный')
else:
    print('Невалидный')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить [`proxies`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) к [сессии](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) `requests`.

***Пример:***

```py
session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'}  # Замените на свой
```

---

P.S.: Функция `requests.session()` является устаревшей с версии 1.0.0, не используйте её.

Comment: Прокси валидный, но в просмотре сессий vk всё равно мой город, а не город прокси